# Amazon Ses emails going very slow

Tags: php

I am trying to send about 28000 email using Amazon SES, but the problem is the emails are going very slow in last 7 hours only 8000 emails were delivered, i have setup a cron job to run the script on the server side to send emails, which was triggered 8 in the morning, and now about 15:23 emails are still going.

I am using phpMailer to send emails through amazon using smtp. How can i make this process to work faster, are there some measures i should undertake?

I have already tried curl to send emails using SES api. But same results. 
My limits are 50000 Emails a day, with delivery of 14/Sec emails.

Comment: Perhaps there are ways of making the job more efficient but it is unlikely someone can guess how without your script. Please add the script code with sensitive values omitted.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon says that mail send rates, which are not especially fast at a max rate of 70 per second (**edit: apparently the rate varies depending on the user*), will be slow if you are using a single thread to create a connection to send mail. They suggest that in order to achieve a higher sending rate per second you should use multithreading which will allow you to create several threads which in turn creates several connections for email delivery.

For how to handle multithreading in PHP there are a number of good answers here on SO on how to implement it (or something like it, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can also put up to 50 addressees in the "Destinations" property when sending via the API.  This would allow you to batch in blocks of 50 per email.  That is, if you can actually do that.  Obviously the emails would have to be the same and not customized per email address.

Another idea would be to spin up a couple more worker nodes to get out these emails.